# Can a Linked Power still affect a target if they're no longer in range?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Let's say there's a psion that uses the Linked Power Metapsionic feat to use power A on a target, linked with power B. If the target teleports away before the psion's next turn, does power B still affect them?

In the specific case I'm thinking of, power A is Primal Fear, and power B is [Death Urge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/deathUrge.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be covered—albeit obliquely—in the feat Linked Power's benefit section by this statement:

> It is possible that by the time the linked power comes into effect on the following round, the area where it goes off **or the target that it affects** no longer has relevance. On the other hand, you are free on the subsequent round to take actions normally. (*Complete Psionic* 63)

(Emphasis mine.) For example, a telepath 10 applies the metapsionic feat Linked Power to the 1st-level psion/wilder power *primal fear* [telepathy] (*CP* 95) and the 4th-level psion/wilder power [*death urge*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#death-urge) [telepathy] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 90). After the telepathy manifests the power *primal surge* on a target, the target employs an effect that moves him 300 ft. from the psion. As the metapsionic feat Linked Power doesn't change the medium range of the telepath's *death urge* power, next round the target is beyond that range, and the target "no longer has relevance."

However, that's my assumption, anyway. Widely considered by fans as one of *3.5e*'s most problematic texts, *Complete Psionic* has a host of issues that can only be resolved by discussing them with the DM, and whether a target "no longer has relevance" is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> It is possible that by the time the linked power comes into effect on the following round, the area where it goes off or the target that it affects no longer has relevance.

Linked Power explicitly says that the target no longer being relevant is a risk with this feat. It definitely does not say that the power can ignore any of its usual parameters.

Most abuses of Linked Power ignore this by using self-targeting buffs (*grip of iron* linked to *synchronicity* being the most notorious).